# How to set rolling window to calculate centered moving average in SAS?

Tags: sas

I need to work out the rolling average over window `(-30, 30)`.

I know that syntax for moving average is something like:

```
proc expand data = try out = ma;
  convert number = av_number / transformout=( movave 30 );
run;
```

But this only includes the window (-30, 0)

Can someone tell me the syntax to work out the average for  `(-30, 30)` ?

Answer (score 4):

You're constructing a *Centered Moving Average*, which is created with the CMOVAVE feature (see [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect026.htm) ):

```
convert number=av_number/transformout=(cmovave 61);
```

61 would be 30 before, itself, and 30 after.